# Is there a way to count how many dojo.require calls occurred and how many were completed?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm trying to create a progress bar that shows the progression of loading the javascript dependencies.
For that I need to know how many dojo.require calls occurred and how many were completed.
Counting how many dojo.require calls occurred is easy and can be done like this:

```
dojo.declare("admin.Bootstrapper", null, {
    requiredDependencies: 0,
    loadedDependencies: 0,
    modules: [],
    _require: null,
    constructor: function()
    {
        this._require = dojo.require;

        dojo.require = dojo.hitch(this, this._loadDependency);
    },
    _loadDependency: function(module)
    {
        this._require(module);

        this.requiredDependencies++;
        console.log("requiredDependencies:" + this.requiredDependencies);

        this.modules.push(module);
    }
});

var bootstrapper = new admin.Bootstrapper();
```

Now I know that dojo.addOnLoad can check if all dojo.require calls are completed but there is no way to check if one require call is completed.
How can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some possibilities:

**1. Go around the problem.**

Use the Dojo [build system](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/build/index.html#build-index) to group all dependencies in a single .js file. No more downloads to track!

**2. Use the new asynchronous modules**

[AMD modules](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2010/11/04/requirejsamd-module-forms/) allow more fine grained dependency management.

```
require(['foo', 'bar'], function ( foo, bar ) {
   //runs after foo and bar are loaded
   //doesn't care about other dependencies
});
```

**3. Synchronize everything**

This is evil in many ways ... but should get the job done if you really need to.

```
dojo.require('first.module');
dojo.ready(function(){
    dojo.require('second.module');
    dojo.ready(function(){
    });
});
```

Comment: I have no control about what the user might do, if they use the build system it's their choice. I'd really like to keep track of the loading itself. I have found a way to do so without considering the sub dependencies but I'd still prefer to be able to track the loading process.

Comment: I don't think I get this 100% then. Are you requiring your own files or are you requiring from an unreliable source somewhere else?

Comment: I request dojo files, my own files, other users might request their own files as well.

Comment: If you only request your own files you know beforehand what they will be so you can bundle them up if you want to (the build tool also works for subsets of the whole project)

Comment: @missingo But I can't guarantee that other users will perform a build as well.

Comment: You could distribute the built file instead. I still don't get why what you are doing is complicated enough to warrant going through all the trouble of tracking the inclusion process.